# When does CoreData actually write to the sqlite file?

Tags: ios, core-data

If my app saves my object to CoreData,  is it reasonable for me to expect that if I close the app and pull the sqlite file from the device I can see my object in sqlite browser immediately?

I've had some issues where I'm saving objects to core data,  but if I close the app and pull the sqlite file I do no see the objects I just created.

Thanks

Comment: Are you also copying the journal file(s)?

Comment: @TomHarrington  no,  can you help me understand what that means?

Comment: Did you disable the boilerplate `saveContext` method in `applicationWillTerminate` in the app delegate?

Comment: @Mundi  yes,  applicationWillTerminate is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 7 shipped, Core Data's default configuration uses multiple files: The core persistent store file and two journal files. If your persistent store were named `Foo.sqlite`, the journal files would be `Foo.sqlite-wal` and `Foo.sqlite-shm`. Core Data creates them automatically.

In normal operation, new changes are written to the `wal` file. They get rolled into the main file on some undocumented schedule.

What this means is that if you copy `Foo.sqlite` but not the others, you won't get all of your data. This is how SQLite works. You can change this behavior in Core Data but I wouldn't recommend it. The journal files help ensure that your data doesn't get corrupted.